# How to divide some string that inside of strings contain int value and string value

Tags: python, string, types, integer, slice

Is it possible to split strings (inside of strings there are 2 type possibilities for example strings and integer) into 2 things without depending on the index of the string? For example:

```
# strings contain 2 possibilities, which is int and str
word = "123abc"
```

I want to make into divide strings based on their type (as you can see, 123 can be changed into integer types and abc cant)

```
# result that i want :  

integer = 123
strings = "abc"
```

but I don't want to use slicing to do that. I want to analyze and divide it based on their type

```
# code that I don't want : 

integer = int(word[0:4])
# integer = 123
strings = word(word[4:])
# strings = "abc"
```

because if I use slicing, if the word change, the code will be useless right?

I'm really curious if dividing by types is possible or not so hehe.. thank you For helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job

```
word = '123abc'

# Create empty lists which you will append to later
integers = []
strings = []

# Go through every letter of the word
for i in word:
    # Try whether the character can be changed to an integer
    try:
        integer = int(i)
        # If so, append it to the integers list
        integers.append(integer)
    except:
        # If not, append it to the strings list
        strings.append(i)

print('strings:', strings)
print('integers:', integers)
```

This prints:

```
strings: ['a', 'b', 'c']
integers: [1, 2, 3]
```